# Sympy left-sided limit of sign function

Tags: python, sympy

I'm studying sympy library for python for my study purpose. I'd like to calculate the next limit: 

[image]

Thus, i have code:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
f = sp.sign(sp.cos(sp.pi/x))
sp.limit(f, x, 2, '-')
```

But I'm getting next error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-56b1fd6b589d> in <module>()
      1 x = sp.Symbol('x')
      2 f = sp.sign(sp.cos(sp.pi/x))
----> 3 sp.limit(f, x, 2, '-')
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\series\limits.py in limit(e, z, z0, dir)
     47     """
     48 
---> 49     return Limit(e, z, z0, dir).doit(deep=False)
     50 
     51 
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\series\limits.py in doit(self, **hints)
    178 
    179         try:
--> 180             r = gruntz(e, z, z0, dir)
    181             if r is S.NaN:
    182                 raise PoleError()
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\series\gruntz.py in gruntz(e, z, z0, dir)
    656         else:
    657             raise NotImplementedError("dir must be '+' or '-'")
--> 658         r = limitinf(e0, z)
    659 
    660     # This is a bit of a heuristic for nice results... we always rewrite
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\series\gruntz.py in limitinf(e, x)
    426         e = e.subs(x, p)
    427         x = p
--> 428     c0, e0 = mrv_leadterm(e, x)
    429     sig = sign(e0, x)
    430     if sig == 1:
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\series\gruntz.py in mrv_leadterm(e, x)
    511     w = Dummy("w", real=True, positive=True, finite=True)
    512     f, logw = rewrite(exps, Omega, x, w)
--> 513     series = calculate_series(f, w, logx=logw)
    514     return series.leadterm(w)
    515 
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\series\gruntz.py in calculate_series(e, x, logx)
    464     from sympy.polys import cancel
    465 
--> 466     for t in e.lseries(x, logx=logx):
    467         t = cancel(t)
    468 
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py in yield_lseries(s)
   2635             def yield_lseries(s):
   2636                 """Return terms of lseries one at a time."""
-> 2637                 for si in s:
   2638                     if not si.is_Add:
   2639                         yield si
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py in _eval_lseries(self, x, logx)
   2700         # terms.
   2701         n = 0
-> 2702         series = self._eval_nseries(x, n=n, logx=logx)
   2703         if not series.is_Order:
   2704             if series.is_Add:
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py in _eval_nseries(self, x, n, logx)
    685         cf = Order(arg.as_leading_term(x), x).getn()
    686         if cf != 0:
--> 687             nterms = int(nterms / cf)
    688         for i in range(nterms):
    689             g = self.taylor_term(i, arg, g)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

What's the problem? I was easily calculating limits and haven't such error before. Is there a way to fix it? I haven't found one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in limit computation; if you haven't encountered such bugs before, it just means you haven't given SymPy sufficiently complicated limits. Non-analytic, piecewise defined functions like abs and sign give a lot of trouble to SymPy's algorithm which is based on series expansions. It sometimes manages the correct answer, sometimes gives a wrong answer, and sometimes no answer at all.

When `sign(something)` does not work, it is reasonable to try `something/Abs(something)`, which is mathematically equivalent but might work better (or worse) in SymPy.

```
f = sp.cos(sp.pi/x) / sp.Abs(sp.cos(sp.pi/x))
sp.limit(f, x, 2, '-')
```

does not raise any exceptions and promptly returns an answer: `1`. Unfortunately, the answer is wrong...

If the problem is made simpler by replacing `pi/x` with a symbol `y` (which now approaches `pi/2` from the *right*), then SymPy gets the correct answer:

```
y = sp.symbols('y')
f = sp.cos(y) / sp.Abs(sp.cos(y))
sp.limit(f, y, sp.pi/2, '+')
```

returns `-1`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! But I still have a question about `y` approaching `pi/2` from the right. Is it because when `x->2-` we kinda increase `x`, and that's why `y` decreases, and it is approaching of `y` from the right. Have I correctly got this moment?

Comment: x->2- means x is a little bit __less__ than 2. Then pi/x is a little bit __more__ than pi/2, because a smaller denominator makes a larger quotient.

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I thought. Thank you.